# Картинка на TBitBtn в Delphi рисуется с неправильным разрешением

Tags: delphi

Использую TBitBtn, картинка становится меньше при запуске проекта, чем при просмотре в редакторе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Редактор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

Важное примечание:
Пишу на маке на виртуалке Parallels desktop, у друга на windows всё работает корректно, но не смотря на это ошибку хотелось бы поправить.

Comment: Свойство формы Scaled как установлено?

Comment: Свойство формы Scaled: True

Comment: Менять пробовали?

Comment: Поставил в False и всё заработало, правда весь остальной интерфейс полетел (стал очень маленьким) Наверно потому что экран 4k. Нету других вариантов как это можно исправить?

Comment: IDE не очень-то хорошо работает с высоким DPI. Часть проблем правят, но не всё ещё.

Comment: А нет возможности сделать +- тоже самое (какойто параметр типа Scaled поменять) только у кнопки?

Comment: Я бы мог и костылёк какой вставить, типа изменения размера кнопки от разрешения экрана, только я не знаю как это расчитывать) Было бы отлично если бы вы както мне с этим помогли (размер фото 72px)

Comment: Нет scaled для кнопки. Посмотрите https://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/making-the-glyph-property-high-dpi-aware-for-tbitbtn-and-tspeedbutton/

Comment: Версия среды, кстати, какая?

Comment: Версия 10.4             ....

Comment: Кстати, вы бы могли вставить свой ответ с ссылкой как решение проблемы, я отмечу его. Так что спасибо) Не костыль, а проблемы Delphi)

Comment: В Александриях (11.x) что-то правят по hi-DPI, но конкретно про это не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причины в неполноценной работе среды Delphi с высоким разрешением.

Для того, чтобы глифы BitBtn/TSpeedButton правильно отображались при работе в системе с Hi-DPI, [есть решение](https://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/making-the-glyph-property-high-dpi-aware-for-tbitbtn-and-tspeedbutton/) с их масштабированием от Zarko Gajic.

Возможно, в последних версиях Delphi (Alexandria) что-то поправлено (проверить не на чем)

Comment: А зачем вообще в 10+ использовать динозавров вроде TBitBtn, если там обычные кнопки могут в иконки?..

Comment: @Alekcvp Не привыкли ещё ;) А их картинки правильно ведут себя при hi-dpi?

Comment: Вот про hi-dpi не проверял, но там картинки обрабатываются ОС, а не VCL, так что предполагаю что да.